# C#, Fluent-API (EF-Core), composite list of one class in two classes should result in two tables of this composite

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've this classes like this model:
Both (A and B) take a list of the class C.

[image: class model]

```
class C {
    public int SomeData {get;set;}
    public int SomeOtherData {get;set;}
}

class ABAbstract{
    List<C> Data {get;set;}
}

class A: ABAbstract{
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

class B: ABAbstract{
    public Int Id {get;set;}
}
```

How can I use the Fulent Api to create the database tables as shown?
Note: The primary keys has different data types (string, integer).

[image: Database tables]

Edit:

Answer to question from @x39
This is related to "Code First".

Comment: Please elaborate further - did you try anything and it's creating something you don't want and you need to fix it? Or do you want to provide exact code as answer?

Comment: Is this related to code first or really about shadow tables? There is a general lack of information what the exact scope of this question is imo.